# Apply filename to label when uploading a file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, file-upload

I have hidden the file uploader input field. I use a label (so I can style it) as the clickable element to upload a file. Here's a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m7eqj9ku/)

I've added a JS workaround to change the text of the label so when you select a file, the text "Upload a file" is replaced by the actual filename.

My problem is getting my code to work with multiple file uploaders. With the code below, no matter which file uploader I click on, the file name populates always the first file upload field only:

**HTML**

```
<p class="hide_this"><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap file-02"><input type="file" name="file-02" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-file" id="file-01" aria-invalid="false"></span><label for="file-01"><span>Upload a file</span></label></p>

<p class="hide_this"><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap file-03"><input type="file" name="file-03" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-file" id="file-02" aria-invalid="false"></span><label for="file-02"><span>Upload a file</span></label></p>

<p class="hide_this"><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap file-04"><input type="file" name="file-04" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-file" id="file-03" aria-invalid="false"></span><label for="file-03"><span>Upload a file</span></label></p>
```

**JS**

```
$('input[type=file]').change(function(){
  var filename = $(this).val().split('\\').pop();
  var idname = $(this).attr('id');
  $('.'+idname).next().find('span').html(filename);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why this isn't working for you is that you have a mismatch of `id`s. You simply need to make the `id` of the `<input>` match the `id` of the related `<span>`.

Here is an updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m7eqj9ku/1/

---

*Note: Don't forget to setup your fiddles to work with external libs*

Answer (score 1):

Try this `$('label[for="'+idname+'"]').find('span').html(filename);`

Comment: Thanks but this appears to stop the label change completely